# Inter portlet communication in liferay

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I am new in liferay. So, I just want to explain my scenario.

Actually I have two portlet on my web page - one is in left side and other is on right side:

- he left side portlet contains two hyperlink say demo1 & demo2.
- And I have another two portlet say demo1Portlet & demo2Portlet.
- Instead of right side portlet "demo1Portlet" will be displayed by
  default.
- Now what I have to do is, if I click on demo2 link then, right side
  portlet will change and it will display "demo2Portlet" and if I click
  on demo1 link then it will display "demo1Portlet" on right side.

Can any one know how I can achieve this task?

Please reply to me as soon as possible.

I am new to liftray, so I don't know whther this can be achieved through IPC or without it. Please explain whatever will be the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of different ways to have portlets talk with each other. Most are covered under the documentation of [IPC](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Inter-portlet+communication;jsessionid=916639CD65CDFFA477343D48BCCAEEC4.node-2)'s and the [descendant](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Client-side+Inter-Portlet+Communication;jsessionid=6CACC5A9C08E957058936D3368E3C24F.node-2) [pages](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Eventing+and+Shared+Render+Parameters;jsessionid=6CACC5A9C08E957058936D3368E3C24F.node-2).

In your case, you should really look at the [client-side](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Client-side+Inter-Portlet+Communication;jsessionid=6CACC5A9C08E957058936D3368E3C24F.node-2) page:

With your basic structure

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="comm-demo">demo[number]</a>
```

You would have this JS on the "transmitter portlet":

```
// you may need to have jQuery instead of $. Liferay may have its own 
// $ function which jQuery shouldn't mess with.
$( function () { 
      $('a.comm-demo').click( function(event) { 
           var txt = $(this).next().val(); // demo<number> 
           Liferay.trigger('click', {text: txt}); 
           return false; 
      }); 
 });
```

Then on the "receiving portlet(s)":

```
 Liferay.bind( 
      'click', 
      function(event, data) { 
           var txt = data.text;
           // this will set all class-of-fields to have the text 
           // "demo<number from above>Portlet"
           $('.class-of-fields')[0].html(txt + "Portlet"); 
           // I believe there is a way to minimize/maximize a portlet by 
           // simulating a mouse click, but research would be needed to 
           // confirm.
 });
```

Comment: +1 about an out of box solution that is not sticked in hook/portlet type of solutions like many solutions seem to be on this category of coding.

Comment: In the portal world I'd recommend the IPC way, as this neatly handles namespacing problems - you could have all kinds of "matching" html on the page that receives such javascript events. Plus, IPC is the way to handle server side reactions to this. However, it's typically involving a page reload.

Also, please note that the code above is using jquery, which has been included in Liferay 5.2 but has been replaced with AlloyUI (a YUI extension) in version 6. And, for use of jQuery, you definitely need to use the compatibility mode, e.g. use "jQuery" where the code above says "$" (as commented)

Comment: Try this link.. Quite helpful..
http://www.velvettools.com/2013/02/inter-portlet-communication-in-liferay.html